# Jstree: I can't reset all the checkboxes to uncheck by default when I reload my tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree, jstree-search

I tried to use  this:

```
$("#jstree_demo_div").jstree("destroy").empty();
```

It removes the checked nodes and reload the tree but does not apply the new changes. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Globally I need to reset my tree with unchecked `checkBox`

Answer (score 14):

this is working nice for me !

```
 $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree(true).deselect_all();
```

Answer (score 2):

for checking all the checkboxes

```
$("#jstree").jstree(true).check_all();
```

for unchecking all the checkboxes

```
$("#jstree").jstree(true).uncheck_all();
```